# How to put some default text in one specific TinyMCE editor?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

Tried below code:
`onActivate={e=>initialiseValue(e,this.props.value)}` //props.value has def text

```
function initialiseValue(e,val){
if(val!=""&&val!=undefined){

   e.target.setContent(e.target.getContent()+val);
}
}
```

The problem here is, everytime I click on tinyMCE editor field, it is putting the value over and over. I want the value to be added at first time while loading and not anymore after that. Tried onLoadContent, but it didn't fire setContent() method. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
function initialiseValue(e,val)
{
    if (val !="" && val != undefined && !e.target.contentAdded)
    {
      e.target.setContent(e.target.getContent()+val);
      e.target.contentAdded = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you !

Comment: glad to have been able to help